# Simple implementation of a multi-part ratio data structure

Tags: data-structures

A multi-part ratio would be an expression of the form:

$e_1:e_2:e_3:\cdots:e_n$

It would have the following properties:

1. When the expressions are natural nos, they can be evaluated to be $$\frac{e_1}{gcd(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)}:\frac{e_2}{gcd(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)}:\cdots:\frac{e_n}{gcd(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)}$$
2. Two ratios (say, $e_1:e_2:e_3$ and $u_1:u_2:u_3$) will be equal iff $e_i=k*u_i \;\forall i$ for some fixed k.

There is no direct implementation of this type available in Mathematica to my knowledge, but I think it would be nice to have one (perhaps in terms of lists).

Comment: Is continued ratio just simply one ratio repeated several times? Why would you need to express it explicitly?

Comment: If `e` and `u` are lists of real numbers like `{e1,e2,e3}` and `{u1,u2,u3}` you can check the equality of ratios `e1:e2:e3` and `u1:u2:u3` with the test `Abs@Dot[e,u]==Norm[e]*Norm[u]`. This will avoid potential divide-by-zero errors to which existing answers are prone.

Comment: No. It is something like 20:30:60:100:1000 such that one doesn't care about the explicit values of the elements as long as a new set of values is a common multiple of the old set.

Comment: I am looking for a an implementation that will allow one to store a set of expressions in this continued fraction form so that one can have equations like f(x):g(x):h(x)==5:6:j(x)  which would mean f(x)/g(x)==5/6, g(x)/h(x)=6/j(x). This sort of information can be thus nicely packaged into continued ratio notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to work in M10.1**

One idea is to use [`FactorList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList) to generate the factors of the expressions, and then remove common factors. The nice thing about this approach is that the output will be normalized, so that one can use [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal) to compare the ratio lists. One refinement is to post-process the output of [`FactorList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList) so that integers get factored as well. Here is some code to do this:

```
factor[p_] := Association @* Map[Apply[Rule]] @ Replace[
    FactorList[p],
    {
        {1,1} -> Sequence[],
        {n_Integer, 1} :> Sequence @@ FactorInteger[n],
        {n_Integer, -1} :> Sequence @@ FactorInteger[1/n]
    },
    {1}
]

Clear[Colon]
Colon[p__] := Module[{ku, res, diff},
    ku = KeyUnion[factor /@ {p}, 0&];
    res = Merge[ku, Min];
    diff = # - res& /@ ku;
    Apply[Colon] @ Map[Apply[Times] @* KeyValueMap[Power]] @ diff /; 
        MinMax[res] != {0, 0}
]
```

A couple examples:

```
Colon[20, 30, 60, 100, 1000] //TeXForm
```

> $2:3:6:10:100$

```
Colon[24 x (2y+y^2+1), 36/z (y+1)] //TeXForm
```

> $2 x (y+1) z:3$

Comment: Sorry, when I execute this code, I am getting errors, saying that the arguments of the association are incompatible

Comment: @SubhobrataChatterjee You probably are using an older M build. I updated things to work in M10.1.

Comment: Thanks. It worked this time. This is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
mytest[a_List, b_List] := Equal @@ MapThread[Divide, {a, b}];

a = {3, 4, 5};
b = {6, 8, 10};

mytest[a,b]
```

True

```
b = {6, 9, 10};

mytest[a,b]
```

False

---

You might find this useful:

```
myratiomaker[start_, factor_, numberofelements_Integer] := 
 StringJoin @@ 
  Riffle[ToString /@ 
    FixedPointList[factor # &, start, numberofelements], ":"]
```

So:

```
myratiomaker[6, .5, 4]
```

(*

"6:3.:1.5:0.75:0.375"

*)

Comment: I think OP askes for data structure for continued proportions, which is something like 1:3:9:27:81, i.e. all ratios are the same.

Comment: "...but I think it would be nice to have one(perhaps in terms of lists)."

Comment: What I mean is that neither `{3,4,5}` or `{6,8,10}` in your example is a continued ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would be useful for providing equality between ratios to `Solve` or `FindInstance` maybe. You can define `\[Colon]` operator to construct such equality for you:

```
Colon[a___] := Equal @@ Divide @@@ Partition[{a}, 2, 1]
```

And then

```
FindInstance[(a \[Colon] b \[Colon] c) && (0 < a < b < c), {a, b, c}, Integers, 2]
```